# Baking normal map results in lighting artifacts

Tags: uv, baking, normal-map

I've been kinda busy and haven't had time to look into baking that much, but watched a blender guru tutorial and gave it a try. I get these triangles and edges at different places, here at both front and back legs.

I am using 2.8. I tried tweaking the ray distance to no avail. Also recalculated normals to make sure they where pointing the right way and applied scale and rotation for both high and low poly mesh. I am guessing it may have to do with the fact that I was lazy and did an auto uv unwrap? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: With that lighting it might very well be terminator effect (assuming Image Texture node with normal map is set to Non-Color and stuff like shading was set to smooth for both objects before baking normal map).

Comment: @MrZak I think it might be the terminator effect from what I've read about it after you mentioned it. There seems to be no solution for this?:(

Comment: Not with that lighting and that geometry. If there were e.g. 1 mln faces for that object it won't be that visible. Probably you want to showcase / use your object in other lighting conditions, like even realistic ones. Then use hdri maps, and / or several lights around etc, not to mention normal maps usage. Also it depends on render engine you're aiming to. If it's game engine chances are you're better off testing right there (though generally should be the same), the thing is lighting in the game is likely to be other than grey.

Comment: @MrZak Turns out I was a bit quick and sloppy with the node setup for the normal map. Just fyi, I'm aiming for photorealism with cycles, but the light was just to test the normal map

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use that lighting for testing normal map, you won't see it anyway. Use hdri maps for quick setup. Make sure also to set normal maps in particular to non-color data in image texture node setup